# Unknown File Encoding - MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

estoy intentado de traer una base de datos a mysql workbench pero me sale este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si selecciono el encoding correspondiente que es utf8, me sale el error siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ahí está más que claro el error, te dice que no tiene la codificación UTF-8, entonces te pide que selecciones el tipo de codificación, solo tienes que seleccionar el tipo que corresponda al archivo que estás seleccionando.

Comment: @omargt8 ahi edite la pregunta, cuando selecciono el encoding correspondiente me salta un error igual.

Comment: crea una copia de backup primero, luego ábrelo con notpad++ y conviértelo a UTF-8 SIN BOM y nos dices si te funciono.

Answer (score 1):

Recomendaciones: nunca modifiques un archivo en editores de texto simples como bloc de notas, puesto que modifica su codificación.
Alguna vez me sucedió y creé una copia, la abrí con notepadd y modifiqué la codificación. También hice una revisión visual para modificar algunos caracteres que habían quedado corruptos, con un replace ajusté y funcionó.